# Inner anti join in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, join, pyspark

I am trying to do inner anti join in pyspark. For example i have a common key in both df, now what i need is to extract all the row which are not common in both df. That is id of one should not match with id of another.

`df1=df1.join(df2,how='inner',df1.id !=df2.id)`

But with this code,I am getting rows those ids are same in both df.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try `left anti join` -

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1['id']==df2['id'], how='left_anti')
df4 = df2.join(df1, df1['id']==df2['id'], how='left_anti')
final_df = df3.unionAll(df4)
```

So we do twice `left anti join` and then `union`.

Answer (score -1):

**Spark allows you to handle such use cases in multiple ways**

**1. Use except : will return a new DataFrame containing rows in dataFrame1 but not in dataframe2.**
**`df1.except(df2)`**

**2. Use subtract, Return a new DataFrame containing rows in this DataFrame but not in another DataFrame.**

**`df1.subtract(df2)`**

**3. Use exceptAll() : Return a new DataFrame containing rows in this DataFrame but not in another DataFrame while preserving duplicates.**

**`df1.exceptAll(df2)`**

**4. Use left_anti join : Key present which is part of DF1 and as well as DF2, should not be part of the resulted dataset**

**`df = df1.join(df2, df1.key == df2.key, "left_anti")`**